# Remote working from home

Tags: vpn

If I agree to remote working with my employer how do they identify my PC? Is it the IP address or is it the computer name or user name I entered when I set up the PC?

Comment: why would they want to identify your PC?

Answer (score 2):

Most remote workers utilise a remote access VPN.  This will require you to authenticate using one of several methods based on pre-shared keys or more likely digital certificates. Your employer may also use third-party methods utilising Token Based Authentication.  Your public IP address can change at any time so they will not be filtering based on this.  They will assign your internal IP as part of the VPN process.

Answer (score 0):

We have not enough data to answer this. Anyway, usually the employer gives you a vpn access. Or maybe only a web access if you work with a web application.

In case of only web access, he is going to log your public Ip (which is going to be the same on every pc at your home), and your User-Agent, which can change depending of the pc/browser, so if you don't want to be detected using a different pc from home to work be sure to reproduce the exact environment or you can fake your user agent which is pretty easy.

If a vpn is given, once connected you are in other network, so they can scan your machine and they can now a lot of more things: open ports, fingerprintng, hostname, mac address, etc... so you are going to be discovered for using different machine very easily and to fake all of that stuff is a little more complicated.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is neither your device or IP address. When you connect to an enterprise VPN you will do so by connecting to a VPN server from a VPN client that has been installed on your device.

It is the information that is supplied to this client that will allow you to be identified. Further to this you may also need to supply some kind of credentials such as domain credentials to access the resources within the domain you are connected to.

A typical client will contain a variety of things covering the various technologies that can be used to set up a VPN, but it is not uncommon to see the following

- What interface on your device to connect from:

  dev vrt0
- An instruction to set up a persistent tunnel:

  Persist-tun
- An instruction to use a  key, which is hard coded into the client.

  persist-key
- Details of where to connect to including port and transport protocol;

  remote yournetwork.yourorg.com 1194 udp

  remote 34.23.222.243 1194 udp